# Detect click event position of an overlapping dot

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is a codepen live demo at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/QWaqyPx).

1)Click on the gird to add first red point

2)Click on the gird to add second red point

3)Click back on the first red point

**Problem:** You will see that the coordinates will change or detected as you click the first and second. However, when you click back the the first point, the coordinates is not detected and perhaps because its overlay. May I ask if there is a solution for this and show a demo:)

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsEQQ.png)

```
.red-dot {
  position:absolute; 
  width:15px; 
  height:15px;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to make it work you can add  `pointer-events: none;` to your CSS.

so it'll look like this:

```
.red-dot {
  position:absolute; 
  width:15px; 
  height:15px;
  background:red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

this way the click will be ignored and applied on the grid it self instead of the red square element

Comment: Thank you, gil for your help. Appreciate that:)